# Union Type - formidable results

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, formidable

I am using the `formidable` module in an Express project.

The typing file for `formidable` contains the following:

```
export interface Files {
    [key: string]: File; // | File[];
}
export interface File {
    name: string;
    //...
}
export declare class IncomingForm extends events.EventEmitter {
    //..
    parse(req: http.IncomingMessage, 
     callback?: (err: any, fields: Fields, files: Files) => any): void;
}
```

Note the commented out `// | File[]` for the definition of `Files`.

I use the `parse` method to get files uploaded at the browser. Actual testing shows that when only one file is uploaded, the `files` object in the callback has a property with key `files` (very confusing use of names) of type `File`. In the debugger it is shown as:

> Object (files: File)

If two files are uploaded, `files.files` is of type `File[]`.

The code works fine without any errors. I am curious why it can either be a single object or an array when the definition left out the array option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though the DefinitelyTyped definitions for formidable are out of date.

As a user, it's a good opportunity for you to fix it and submit a pull request here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/formidable/index.d.ts

Comment: With this defintion, files will always be an object mapping any string to one file. `{foo: {....}, bar: {...}}` but never `{foo: [{...}, {...}]}` I'd be very surprised if TypeScript allowed you otherwise, and would love to see code that works where `files.something` is an array.

Comment: I used `Array.isArrary(files.files)` to differentiate the two situations and it returns `true`/`false` as expected. (I am referring to the result that is passed back from the `parse` method.)

Comment: `Array.isArray` accepts an `any`, it's a test function, so it makes sense to accept any value, you are allowed to call `Array.isArray(4)` for example.